# Unable to use bpmn.js, bpmn-viewer.js, differ.js and change-handler.js files in angular project

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, bpmn.io

Cloned the BPMN diffing project ([link](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-diffing)). The JS files used here are of NodeJs environment. Hence on adding these in angular project giving error like - `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`.
Besides this, there are other libraries inside these files which have been called, these return error too. For example - `require('bpmn-js/lib/features/movecanvas')`.

Need to find a solution to use these `js` files in angular project and reuse the functionality written in the `app.js` file for checking differences in two BPMN workflows.